# git log --grep does not work in windows

Tags: windows, git, grep, git-log

Is there any equivalent for **"git log --grep="STRING"** in **windows?**

I've written a python program for linux which requires a reading of commit logs that contain certain string from the git object. This worked fine in linux, but when I ran the same program in windows, **git log --grep="STRING"** catches nothing.

Here's the code snippet. (fetcher.py)

```
import os
...
os.chdir(DIRECTORY) # where git obj is
command = "git log --all --grep='KEYWORD' > log.txt"
os.system(command) # run the command in the shell
...
```

It seems that git internally uses the linux grep for the "--grep" argument such that Windows cannot run this correctly as it misses grep.

Thanks for your help.

---

As I am not getting any answer for 24 hrs,
I suggest my own solution, which does not utilize grep.

Because **git log** itself runs without any problem,
I just ran the command without the --grep='STRING' option, then read the output from the shell (or a file) to filter the commit logs which contain 'STRING' by the use of regular expression.

```
import os
import re

command = "git log --all > log.txt"
os.system(command) # run the command in the shell and store output in log.txt

with open('log.txt', 'r') as fp:
    gitlogoutput = fp.readlines() # read the redirected output

if gitlogoutput:
    commits = re.split('[\n](?=commit\s\w{40}\nAuthor:\s)', gitlogoutput)
    # it splits the output string into each commits
    # at every '\n' which is followed by the string 'commit shahash(40bytes)\nAuthor: '

    for commit it commits:
        if 'KEYWORD' is in commit:
            print commit
```

The approach requires you to add some code, but I believe it does the same thing as the original command does. For better results, you can change the last if statement which is,

```
if 'KEYWORD' is in commit:
```

into something that can do more sophisticated search e.g. re.search() method.
In my case, this produced exactly the same result as that of --grep="KEYWORD"

Still, I appreciate your help :)

Answer (score 2):

> It seems that git internally uses the linux grep for the "`--grep`" argument such that Windows cannot run this correctly as it misses grep.

It certainly can, provided your `%PATH%` includes `<git>/usr/bin` (which has 200+ Linux commands compiled for Windows)

See this simplified path:

```
set G=c:\path\to\latest\git
set PATH=%G%\bin;%G%\usr\bin;%G%\mingw64\bin
set PATH=%PATH%;C:\windows\system32;C:\windows\System32\Wbem;C:\windows\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\
```

Add the PATH for python, and you can "Linux grep" without any issue.

Answer (score 0):

In Windows, use the following format (replacing the `=` sign with a space):

```
git log --grep "STRING"
```